# Issue in single-table design DynamoDB and limit query parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, limit

I want to be able to limit the fetch elements I am getting in each query, but I am facing the following issue here:

Since I use the single-table design in DynamoDB I am getting only four items here:

[image]

If I check the 10 first elements in DynamoDB, I will notice that I am getting the count here, regardless of the items I am filtering in my Scan operation
[image]

```
  async paginate<TEntity>(
    limit = 10,
    start_key: any
    TableName = $env.MAIN_TABLE
  ): Promise<Paginate<TEntity>> {
    Assert.ok(TableName)
    const items= await this.instance.scan({
       TableName
       Limit: limit,
       ExclusiveStartKey: start_key,
       FilterExpression: 'contains(PK, :PK)',
       ExpressionAttributeValues: {
         ':PK': 'QUIZ#'
       }
    })
    return items
  }
```

Does anyone here know a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a `Scan` with `Limit=10` and also providing a `FilterExpression` which means DynamoDB will first read the first 10 items, then evaluate the FilterExpression and return which ever items in that batch of 10 evaluate to your filter as True.

[First line of docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html)

> A single Scan operation reads up to the maximum number of items set (if using the Limit parameter) or a maximum of 1 MB of data and then apply any filtering to the results using FilterExpression. If LastEvaluatedKey is present in the response, you need to paginate the result set. For more information, see Paginating the Results in the Amazon DynamoDB Developer Guide.

**The bottom line is that you will need to paginate to achieve 10 items.**

My advice is that you should never model your data where you need a contains for the partition key lookup